# how to click the span element in dropdown by selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to click smartphone element in dropdown by selenium Web driver?please find the code

```
<div id="tooltip_menu">
<li class="level0 nav-1 first level-top"
<a class="level-top" onclick="event1('Smart Phones')" href="http://www.vmall.my/index.php/smart-phones.html">
<span>Smart Phones</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an XPath expression, like this:

```
//span[text()='Smart Phones']
```

Set your expression to a By locator variable, say **SmartPhoneSelectionLocator**,

and then in your test, use `SmartPhoneSelectionLocator.click();`

So perhaps the code in your Page Object would look like:

```
By SmartPhoneSelectionLocator = By.xpath("//span[text()='Smart Phones']");
```

Also, it's recommended you actually wrap the behavior of the above action in a method in your Page Object.

Comment: still i'm not able to click                                                                   
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
try {
 Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
}
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Smart Phones']")).click();
}
}

Comment: I recommend you use Expected Conditions instead of sleeps, when using WebDriver.  Sleeps are never recommended.  https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html.  I'd tighten up the first xpath as well.  Why not do something like `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='tooltip-menu']//a")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

Please inspect on selecting the value which frame has been loaded on webpage. You have to switch to that frame then select the value from dropdown.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(name_or_id);
```

now select the dropdown. hope it will work for you.